# Can't delete a JPA entity that is part of a @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two domain objects like so:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false, name = "id")
  protected Integer id;

  // Note: org_id is just an integer column in the database
  @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "org_id")
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Org.class)
  private Org org;
}
```

...and:

```
@Entity
public class Org {
  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false, name = "id")
  protected Integer id;
}
```

I've come to the situation in my logic where I need to make some drastic changes to what's actually saved in the database. i.e. some Orgs are getting deleted and the Employees who were in them are getting re-allocated.

The issue I have is that my program logic currently does the following:

1. Delete any Employees that need to be deleted via `org.springframework.data.repository.delete(Iterable<? extends T> itrbl)`
2. Delete any Orgs that need to be deleted via `org.springframework.data.repository.delete(Iterable<? extends T> itrbl)`
3. Create new/update existing Orgs via `org.springframework.data.repository.save(Iterable<S> itrbl)`
4. Create new/update existing Employees via `org.springframework.data.repository.save(Iterable<S> itrbl)`

The issue comes about at step 2. I get an exception like this:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
>   unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing : com.sample.domain.Employee.org -> com.sample.domain.Org;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
>   unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing : com.sample.domain.Employee.org
>   -> com.sample.domain.Org

If an Org ends up with no employees I don't want to delete the Org. Likewise, if an Employee of an Org gets deleted I don't want the Org to be deleted either.

I essentially just want something that's the same as how I've got the foreign key setup in PostgreSQL on the `employees` table:

```
  CONSTRAINT fk_employees_org_id FOREIGN KEY (org_id)
      REFERENCES public.orgs (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL
```

I've looked at the cascade options, and I'm not sure it's applicable seeing as it's not a straight parent/child relationship (and the `Employee` that defines the `@ManyToOne` relationship isn't really the parent - it's the child) and it's not bi-directional (there's no need for an Org to have a list of all of its Employees)

Comment: You dont want cascade, since you've said yourself you dont want related objects to be deleted. So, if an `Org` needs to be deleted yet still has a FK pointing to it, then just null out the link to the `Org` in the `Employee`(s) ... PRIOR to delete of the `Org`.

Comment: @NeilStockton - thanks, that's just the pointer I needed (have been staring at this issue for too long to see the obvious!). If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want `cascade`, since you've said yourself you don't want related objects to be deleted (and that's all that cascade does).

If an `Org` needs to be deleted yet still has a FK pointing to it, then just null out the link to the `Org` in the `Employee`(s) ... PRIOR to delete of the `Org`. You can do this via a JPQL query to retrieve all `Employee` objects linked to a particular `Org`, and then null their relation field. Alternatively a Bulk Update could do it in one go (but be careful about in-memory objects since they would need `refresh`() calling on them to pick up this nulling of the FK).